# Access ReactJS's internal event mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, dom-events

Since ReactJS uses event delegation, is there a way to access the internal node/events mapping?

It doesn't have to be pretty, wrapping one of the responsible functions (like the equivalent of jQuery's `on()`) and doing custom housekeeping would work fine and would actually be preferable to accessing that data through an object of some sort.

If I could get the selector, event and handler (optional) that'd be great, as I'm already doing this for jQuery.

The reason I'm asking is because I'm trying to optimize [Arachni](http://www.arachni-scanner.com/) for ReactJS applications and having prior knowledge of which elements actually have event handlers (and what they are) would result in a much more efficient scan.

In addition, that data would be of great value when scanning web applications for non security reason's as well, you could gather some very interesting stats that way.

Comment: are you asking for how to access all the `SyntheticEvent`'s created?

Comment: @mattclemens No that would be too late, I'm interested in intercepting or getting a glimpse into the event binding phase, rather than the firing one. I'd basically like to know which nodes have listeners for which events. This gets tricky though as ReactJS doesn't attach events to nodes directly but to some ancestor.